# Soco, pause in group

Tags: python, sonos

I am trying to make my own songs application using python 3. I have installed SoCo from the pip3 command. I currently have this script (called find.py).

```
import time, soco, sys
def search_for_speaker(speaker_name):
    global zone_list
    zone_list = list(soco.discover())

    for speaker in zone_list:
        if speaker.player_name == speaker_name:
            global player
            player = speaker

search_for_speaker(sys.argv[1])
player.pause()
time.sleep(1)
player.play()
```

The speakers I have in my house are called `Hallway`, `Kitchen` and `Living Room`. `Hallway` and `Kitchen` are in a group while `Living Room` is on its own.

When I run `python3 find.py Living\ Room`, the script pauses the speaker then plays again. Same goes for when I run `python3 find.py Kitchen`. The issue is when I try `python3 find.py Hallway`. I end up getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "find.py", line 12, in <module>
    player.pause()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/soco/core.py", line 94, in inner_function
    raise SoCoSlaveException(message)
soco.exceptions.SoCoSlaveException: The method or property "pause" can only be called/used on the coordinator in a group
```

I guess this is because the speaker `kitchen` is the 'master' speaker, while the 'Hallway' one isn't'.

What would I need to do to get this working? I want to be able to play/pause go next/previous on a track and change volume.

I know I could change the name of the speaker when running the script however I am not going to be running it via the command line, instead this will be from the Better Touch Tool Remote (iOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the exception: when Sonos players are grouped, one player has the special role of "group coordinator". All commands that affect the state of the entire group need to be sent to the group coordinator. In SoCo, you can achieve that by calling

```
player.group.coordinator.play()
```

---

Disclaimer: SoCo is (an awesome library and) not supported or endorsed by Sonos.